# Statements in Java

Tags: english, computer-puzzle

Each code block translates to a specific statement in English. There is a theme behind the statements. As code puzzles tend to be "easier" (relative to other PSE puzzles) than expected, it will not be revealed unless people are unable to make any progress on the phrases.

**1:**

```
public class Statement() {
   void Riddle1() {
      Citizen you = new Citizen();
      Government() g = new Government();
      \\g.getService(you)
      \\after a code revision, I've determined the following is better:
      you.getService(g)
   }
}
```

**2:**

```
System.out.println(listofconcerns.length); \\returns 1
System.out.println(listofconcerns[0]); \\returns the string "concerns"
```

**3:**

```
(house has been declared and initialized at some point before this line)
int quotient = house/house;
Boolean b = quotient == 1;
System.out.println(b); \\returns false, with a compiler specific error on the result not holding up
```

**4:**

```
int anglevel = anger();
if(anglevel > threshold1) {
    wait(10000);
    if( anglevel > threshold2) {
       wait(90000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Statement() {
   void Riddle1() {
      Citizen you = new Citizen();
      Government() g = new Government();
      \\g.getService(you)
      \\after a code revision, I've determined the following is better:
```

> Ask not what your country can do for you...

```
      you.getService(g)
```

> ...ask what you can do for your country.

```
   }
}

System.out.println(listofconcerns.length); \\returns 1
```

> The only thing we have to fear... (*"listofconcerns" has just one item*)

```
System.out.println(listofconcerns[0]); \\returns the string "concerns"
```

> ...is fear itself

```
(house has been declared and initialized at some point before this line)
int quotient = house/house;
```

> A house divided against itself...

```
Boolean b = quotient == 1;
System.out.println(b); \\returns false, with a compiler specific error on the result not holding up
```

> ...cannot stand (*does not hold up*)

```
int anglevel = anger();
if(anglevel > threshold1) {
```

> When angry...

```
    wait(10000);
```

> count to ten before you speak. (*wait() is in milliseconds*)

```
    if( anglevel > threshold2) {
```

> If very angry...

```
       wait(90000);
```

> ...count to one hundred. (*we've already counted to 10 at this point, so 10+90*)

```
    }
}
```

**Theme**:

> Things said by dead american presidents: Kennedy, Roosevelt, Lincoln, and Jefferson respectively.

Comment: Correct. I suppose there's no way that code puzzles like these will ever be too difficult.

Comment: @Displayname Putting them together makes them easier, because once you get one, you get a hint to the others. However, _easy_ doesn't mean _bad_, I think theme makes it better.